# Prove family of sets is not mutually disjoint

Tags: abstract-algebra

The follow question appeared in my abstract algebra text:

> Prove
>
> 1. $\{\mathbb{Z}_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ are not mutually disjoint, where $\mathbb{Z}_n = \{m\in\mathbb{Z}: m-n=3k \text{ for some } k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$
> 2. The sets $\{\mathbb{Z}_n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ are mutually disjoint

It is hard for me to imagine what (1) means. If I take $n_1 \ne n_2$ then $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1} = \{ m \}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{n_2} = \{ m^\prime \}$ and $m \ne m^\prime$ because solutions to $m-n=3k$ are unique, i.e. if $m = m^\prime$ then $3k-n_1 = 3k-n_2$ but $n_1 \ne n_2$!

So can someone reinterpret (1) so that it makes sense? Am I supposed to assume that "*for some $k$*" means more than one $k$?

Thanks for your help

Comment: yes, "for some" can be replaced by "there exists" in this sentence, since it's asserting that for *each* $m$, there is *some* $k$

Comment: Got it. That makes a lot more sense. Thanks